# How do I find the DIV in which my cursor is placed at any moment

Tags: browser, formatting, html

How do I find the DIV in which my cursor is placed at any moment, so I can change the formatting of that area.

Answer (score 4):

I imagine what you are looking for is the CSS `:hover` pseudo selector. It is supported in almost every browser (In IE6 it only works on `a` elements). In your CSS file you could do something like this:

```
div:hover { background: red, border: solid 1px #000 }
```

Which would cause any `div` to change color when the mouse cursor is over the element.

You would of course scope it to just the `divs` you wanted to change:

```
#thisDiv:hover, .special:hover { background: blue }
```

For IE6 you can either choose not to support that functionality, or you can use javascript to add and remove `.hover` classes from the elements, then add that selector to your CSS rules as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that anything exists to find that directly.  You could update the formatting with `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events for the divs.